# How a contract notifies its event listener when an event trigged?

Tags: contract-development

It's confusing for me about how the event listener obtains event in time.

Does it mean the listener APP(web3 code) keeps online and just waiting for notificaiton from the contract generating event, or listener APP checks event record written in block data and get the event info itself?

How to understand the procedure about event generation, notificaiton, and so on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are written in transaction topics, or event logs. You can see an example for example here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6ea1de3dbb191441854f1161bd7b9818a549ce8f7e0b4f0da76bccc78f1473b6#eventlog (an ERC20 token transfer).

So the contract emits the event, the event gets stored inside the transaction and backend systems (programs outside the blockchain) monitor transactions for such events. This is also how web3 operates: it monitors blocks for the right events in the right contract.

Comment: Why the event be written both in transation topics and event logs? Is it periodical for APP ouside blockchain to read event info from the two sources?Thanks.

Comment: It's not written in both, it's just called with different names in different places

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I have the same doubt. My backend consists of a component written in node.js and a node (geth) that communicates with the blockchain. When you say that the backend system monitors events do you mean the component written in external node.js or the geth node?

Comment: @MarioRoma Geth acts as the client to the blockchain and it provides interfaces to get information from the blockchain - so whatever systems you build which utilize those interfaces. It may be based on nodejs or something else.